# Does anyone have a list of SCUBA diving related terms in Chinese?

Tags: mandarin, sport

Things like regulator, atmospheric-air filled tank, nitrox, snorkel. Helpful!

Answer (score 4):

[潜水词汇中英对照大全--潜游世界无障碍—转自TOPPLAYER潜水](http://www.chinascubadiving.com/main/raidersdetails-did-68.html)

> 潜水机构
>
> 世界水中教育联盟 CMAS
>
> 专业潜水教练协会 PADI
>
> 国际潜水教练协会 NAUI
>
> 国际潜水学校联盟 SSI
>
> 中华民国潜水协会 CTDA
>
> 世界水下科技协会 UTDA
>
> 美国海洋大气总署 NOAA
>
> 潜水员急救网路 DAN
>
> 潜水科技协会 DSAT
>
> 世界潜水器材展 DEMA
>
> 潜水类型
>
> 潜水 Diving
>
> 浮潜 Skin Diving（Snorkeling)
>
> 闭气潜水 Free Diving
>
> 水面供气潜水 Air Supply Diving-Hose
>
> 水肺潜水 Scuba Diving
>
> 商业潜水 Commercial Diving
>
> 工业潜水 Industtrialized Diving
>
> 体验潜水 Discover Scuba Diving (DSD)
>
> 岸潜 Shore Dive
>
> 船潜 Boat Dive
>
> 深潜 Deep Dive
>
> 夜潜 Night Dive
>
> 冰潜 Ice Dive
>
> 水下导航 Underwater Navigation
>
> 放流潜水 Drift Dive
>
> 垃圾潜水（漫潜）Muck Diving
>
> 技术导向潜水 TEC Dive
>
> 高海拔潜水 Altitude Dive
>
> 洞穴潜水 Cave or Cavern Dive
>
> 沉船潜水 Wreck Dive
>
> 水中摄影 Underwater Photography
>
> 巡弋漫游 Vehicle Cruise
>
> 搜索寻回 Search And Recovery
>
> 低能见度潜水 Limited Visibility Diving
>
> 多重深度饱和潜水 Multi-Level Dive
>
> 水面闭封潜水环境 Overhead Environments
>
> 装备篇
>
> 轻装 Snorkeling Equipment
>
> 重装 Scuba Equipment
>
> 面镜 Mask
>
> 呼吸管 Snorkel
>
> 呼吸管固定扣 Snorkel Attachement
>
> 头套 Hoods
>
> 溼式防寒衣 Wetsuit
>
> 乾式防寒衣 Drysuit
>
> 排气阀 Deflator Valve
>
> 手套 Scuba Gloves
>
> 活塞平横式 Balanced Piston Type
>
> 低压出器孔 Low Pressure Contact Port
>
> 高压出气孔 High Pressure Contact Port
>
> 低压管 Low Pressure Hose
>
> 高压管 High Pressure Hose
>
> 二级头 Second Stage
>
> 顺流式 Downstream Valves Type
>
> 咬嘴 Mouthpiece
>
> 备用气源 Alternate Air Source
>
> 备用二级头 Safe Second Stage
>
> 章鱼式 Octopus Alternate Air Source
>
> 潜水仪表 Instrument Console
>
> 残压表 Perssure Gauge/SPG
>
> 深度表 Depth Gauge
>
> 气瓶 Cylinderor Scuba Tank
>
> 气瓶开关 Tank Valves
>
> 螺旋式气瓶开关 DIN Valves
>
> 臂抱式气瓶开关 Yoke Valves
>
> 气密圈 O-Ring
>
> 调节器 Regulator
>
> 一级头 First Stage
>
> 隔膜平横式 Balanced Diaphragm Type
>
> 指北针 Compass
>
> 水中通讯器 Underwater Radio
>
> 求援浮力棒 Signal Tube or Surface marker buoy or Sausage
>
> 浮力扬升袋 Liffing Bag
>
> 潜水装备袋 Gear Bag
>
> 蜂鸣器 Air Horn
>
> 定位回声系统 Sonar
>
> 水中推进器 Subscooteror Subtransporter
>
> 水下遥控无人载具 ROV
>
> 密闭式循环水肺系统 Semi-Closed
>
> 防水盒 Waterproof Case
>
> 浮球 Surface Floats
>
> 渔枪 Spear Gun
>
> 备用零件 Spare Parts
>
> 漏气 Free Flow
>
> 水压测试 Pressure Test
>
> 潜水证照 Certification Card
>
> 潜水日志 Diving Log
>
> 潜航准线 Lubber Line
>
> 磁针 Magnetic Needle
>
> 定位转盘 Bezel
>
> 潜水电脑 Diving Computer
>
> 浮力调整背心 Buoyancy Control Device
>
> 充排气阀开关 BCD Inflator Valve
>
> 快速接头 Hose Rapid Adapter
>
> 充气钮 Inflator Button
>
> 排气钮 Deflator Button
>
> 水下手电筒 Marine Light
>
> 闪明器 Flash Light
>
> 萤光棒 Light Stick
>
> 水下记录板 Dive Slate
>
> 渔网 Fishing Net
>
> 缠绕 Entanglement
>
> 救援 Rescue
>
> 潜水靴 Diving Boots 蛙鞋 Fins
>
> 配重带 Weight Belt
>
> 快卸扣 Quick-Release Buckle
>
> 铅块 Weights
>
> 铅块止滑扣 Weight Retainer
>
> 潜水刀 Diving Knife
>
> 潜水员级别
>
> 潜水员 Diver
>
> 初级潜水员 Openwater Diver
>
> 中级潜水员 Advanced Diver
>
> 专项潜水员 Specialty Diver
>
> 高级潜水员 Master Scuba Diver
>
> 潜水长 Dive master
>
> 教练 Instructor
>
> 教练训练员 Instructor Trainer
>
> 课程总监 Course Director
>
> 潜水术语
>
> 空气 Air
>
> 废气 Exhaust
>
> 氧气 Oxygen
>
> 氮气 Nitorgen
>
> 高氧气体 Nitrox
>
> 氦氧氮混合气体 Trimix
>
> 氦氧混合气体 Heliox
>
> 气瓶充气站 Refil Station
>
> 充气压缩机 Air Pump
>
> 气瓶充气 Fill Tank
>
> 充气-对气瓶 Refil Air
>
> 充气-对背心 Inflate
>
> 空气消耗量 Air Amount Used
>
> 人体空腔 Body Air Space
>
> 耳腔 Ear Air Space
>
> 耳膜 Eardrum
>
> 副鼻腔 Sinus Air Space
>
> 气道 Airway
>
> 胸腔 Chest
>
> 肺泡 Pulmonary Alveolus
>
> 潮气肺容积 Tidal Volumn
>
> 最大肺活量 Vital Capacity
>
> 无效能的肺馀容积 Residual Volumn
>
> 气压 Air Pressure
>
> 水压 Water Pressure
>
> 绝对压力 Absolute Atmosphere
>
> 压缩 Squeeze
>
> 气体分压 Percentage of Air
>
> 立方英迟 Cubic-Feet
>
> 公斤平方公分 Bar
>
> 英磅平方英吋 PSI
>
> 体积 Volume
>
> 水容积 Water Container Volume
>
> 浮力 Buoyance
>
> 正浮力 Positive
>
> 中性浮力 Neutral
>
> 负浮力 Negative
>
> 沉 Sink
>
> 浮 Float
>
> 悬浮 Hovering
>
> 光线折射 Refraction
>
> 色温 Color Temperature
>
> 潜伴 Diving Buddy
>
> 潜伴制度 Buddy System
>
> 潜导 Team Leader/Guide
>
> 押队 Team Holder/Keeper
>
> 水下通讯手势 Communication Signals
>
> 潜水计划 Dive Planning
>
> 潜水地点 Dive Site
>
> 下潜简报 Dive Procedures/Briefing
>
> 著装 Suiting Up
>
> 下水前的装备检查 Final Check/Safety Check
>
> 技能评估性质的下潜 Check Dive
>
> 入水点 Entry Point
>
> 入水 Entering The Water
>
> 上岸 Exiting The Water
>
> 风险 Potential Hazards
>
> 跨步式入水 Giant Stride Entry
>
> 背滚式入水 Backward Roll Entry
>
> 镰刀式入水 Headfirst Long Entry
>
> 面镜排水 Mask Clearing
>
> 调节器复位 Regulator Recovery
>
> 调节器排水 Regulator Clearing
>
> 压力平衡 Equalize
>
> 耳压平衡 Equalization/Ears Clearing
>
> 呼吸 Breathing
>
> 共气 Buddy Breathe
>
> 呼气 Exhale
>
> 吸气 Inhale
>
> 憋气 Breath-Hold
>
> 上浮 Ascents
>
> 下沉 Descents
>
> 踢动蛙鞋 Use Fins
>
> 平静水域 Confined Water
>
> 开放水域 Open Water
>
> 海洋相关
>
> 海岸 Shore
>
> 海湾 Gulf
>
> 潮汐 Tides
>
> 涨潮 Incoming High Tide
>
> 满潮 High Tide
>
> 退潮 Outgoing Low Tide
>
> 平潮 Low Tide
>
> 波浪 Surf
>
> 碎浪区 Surfzone
>
> 涌浪 Waves
>
> 海流 Ocean Currents
>
> 潮流 Tides Currents
>
> 洋流 Relatively Premanent Currents
>
> 激流 Rushing Water
>
> 激流区 Rip Dispersal Area
>
> 沿岸流 Down Shore Current
>
> 回流 Undertow
>
> 涌昇流 Up Current
>
> 下降流 Down Current
>
> 漩涡 Eddy Current
>
> 能见度 Visibility
>
> 水底 Bottom
>
> 水中 Underwater
>
> 水面 Surface
>
> 珊瑚礁 Reef
>
> 堡礁 Barrier Reef
>
> 裙礁 Fringing Reef
>
> 环礁 Atoll Reef
>
> 人工鱼礁 Artificial Reef
>
> 沉船 Wreck
>
> 泻湖 Lagoon
>
> 温带 Temperate
>
> 热带 Tropical
>
> 寒带 Polar
>
> 淡水 Freshwater
>
> 海水 Saltwater
>
> 圣婴现象 El Nino
>
> 温室效应 Global Warming
>
> 病症
>
> 过度换气 Hyperventilation
>
> 氮醉 Nitrogen Narcosis
>
> 心肺复苏术 CPR
>
> 失温 HeatLoss
>
> 恐慌 Panic
>
> 抽筋 Cramp
>
> 脱水 Dehydration
>
> 氧中毒 Oxygen Toxicity
>
> 浅层水域昏迷 Ascent Unconsciousness
>
> 减压症 Decompression Sickness
>
> 气泡 Bubbles
>
> 呛水 Inhaled Water
>
> 溺水 Drowning
>
> 窒息 Choking
>
> 急救 First Aid
>
> 抗组织氨 Anti-Histamine
>
> 再压舱 Recompression Chamber
>
> 潜水医学 Underwater Medicine
>
> 潜船
>
> 水平线 Horizen
>
> 潜水船 Diving Boat
>
> 上船登艇 Boarding
>
> 船长 Captain
>
> 甲板 Deck
>
> 航行中 Underway
>
> 船首 Bow
>
> 走向船首 Forward Bow
>
> 左舷 Portside
>
> 走向左舷 On The Portside
>
> 右舷 Starboard
>
> 走向右舷 On The Starboard
>
> 船尾 Stern
>
> 走向船尾 Aft Stern
>
> 下锚 Anchors
>
> 锚绳 Anchor Line
>
> 下风处 Leeward Side
>
> 晕船 Seasickness
>
> 水中生物
>
> 一群鱼 A School of Fish
>
> 鲨鱼 Shark
>
> 梭鱼 Barracuda
>
> 刺魟鱼 Sting Ray
>
> 魔鬼魟鱼 Manta
>
> 狮子鱼 Lionfish
>
> 石头鱼 Rockfish
>
> 粗皮鲷 Surgeon fish
>
> 鲽鱼 Butterfly fish
>
> 盒子鱼 Boxfish
>
> 扳机鱼 Triggerfish
>
> 海豚 Dolphin
>
> 薯鳗 Moray Eel
>
> 鲶鱼/沙毛 Catfish
>
> 火鱼 Firefish
>
> 水母 Jellyfish
>
> 海星 Starfish
>
> 海胆 Sea Urchin
>
> 海蛇 Sea Snake
>
> 章鱼 Octopus
>
> 芋贝 Cone
>
> 珊瑚 Coral
>
> 行程/旅游
>
> 渡假村 Resort
>
> 免费迎宾饮料 Welcome Drink
>
> 面海房 Ocean view
>
> 菲律宾八爪船 Banca
>
> 敞蓬快艇 Open Yacht
>
> 盖舱快艇 Cabin Boat
>
> 独木舟 Kayak
>
> 沙滩排球 Beach Volleyball
>
> 海滩饮料吧 Beach Bar
>
> 大厅 Lobby
>
> 柜檯 Front desk
>
> 筷子 Chopstick

Comment: This is a great list and very helpful, however, are there pinyin to go along with this list? Many of these characters are beyond my level. Thanks!

Comment: You should try Pleco (app software) - handy for pinyin

Comment: Use any online Chinese dictionary and you'll find the corresponding pinyin for each word.